# Barcode in Excel 2010

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, barcode

I need for my company the possibility to create easy a barcode in excel. It should convert 123456 into a Barcode Code 128. Is this possible? We don't want to download a Software or any other stuff that connects with the internet.

It should be easy. I know i can use Wolfram alpha online, that would work, but it's to complicated.

Is it possible to work with a font? No Marco in Excel? What would you suggest me?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13909248/generating-code-128-barcodes-using-excel-vba

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do this is to use a font which is a barcode.

I've done this and used the `Code 39` from http://www.barcodesinc.com/free-barcode-font/